# While starting cqlsh shell it give me error for connecting to cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to connect with cqlsh but it gives me following error :

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': 
    error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)].
    Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I have tried cqlsh command on terminal:

```
cqlsh
```

Comment: please add more information - what OS, what Cassandra version, what Java version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are not providing an IP address for cqlsh to connect to.  It then assumes the "home" IP (127.0.0.1), and I'm guessing that you do not have a running Cassandra node bound to that address.

First, `grep` for the address that your node is binding to:

```
$ grep "_address:" cassandra.yaml 

listen_address: 192.168.1.3 
broadcast_address: 10.2.1.30
rpc_address: 192.168.1.3 
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.2.1.30
```

If your `broadcast_`addresses are different from the defined listen/rpc addresses, you should use that one (internal vs. external IPs...you want the external).  In this case, the cqlsh command would then look something like this:

```
cqlsh 10.2.1.30 -u username -p password
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few scenarios that could answer your question:
1) Cassandra isn't running
2) Cassandra isn't listening/running with that host/IP (127.0.0.1)
3) Cassandra isn't listening on port 9042
4) A firewall is blocking that host/port

1) Check that it's running with

```
ps -ef | grep cassandra (or dse if using dse)
```

2) Check native_transport_address in the cassandra.yaml to see the IP used for the host. 0.0.0.0 is perfectly fine (if you set the native_transport_broadcast_address)

3) Check the native_transport_port in the cassandra.yaml to see the port used

4) Telnet to host/port to ensure nothing is in the way

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9042
```

You should see output that looks similar to this:

```
Connected to XXXXXXXX.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you don't, and all the other checks pass, something is in the way (firewall).

Note that the parameters used in the cassandra.yaml are for Cassandra 3.11 (I believe dse 5.X+). If using older versions, the parameters are different.

-Jim

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution two queries have to run one by one that are follows on terminal.

1. cassandra
2. cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042(port)